# Qt and wwWidgets - QwwButtonLineEdit

Tags: qt, qt4.7, wwwidgets

I'm working with Qt 4.7 and wwWidgets 1.0 (a set of widgets for Qt), and I'm trying to use `QwwButtonLineEdit`. I just placed the widget on the window and ran the app. But something went (very) wrong. An obscure error appeared:

> ./debug\ViewCadastrarEstagiario.o:ViewCadastrarEstagiario.cpp:(.text$_ZN26Ui_ViewCadastrarEstagiario7setupUiEP7QWidget[Ui_ViewCadastrarEstagiario::setupUi(QWidget*)]+0x141c): undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN17QwwButtonLineEditC1EP7QWidget'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Where `ViewCadastrarEstagiario` is my window.

I didn't change the name, nor any other property. I just placed the widget and ran the application, and this weird error jumped in my face.

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here: http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/#usage ? I'm assuming you're basically forgetting to link against wwWidgets static library files. Haven't used it myself, so I could be wrong, but check this.

Comment: Yep. I placed the "config += wwwidgets" and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to add the library to project folder. My bad!